# how to filter and count a table value by month

Tags: sql

I have a database with:

- user_id
- impressions
- date

A new record is added to the table every time an imp was received (who received, how much, and when).

Question: how to filter and count unique userid's, who received less than 3 impressions during one month, but in some other (any) month of the year received more than 3 imp? (Assuming that user_id's aren't a stable number of people, but new/different users can be added any day/month)

I can't wrap my head around an algorithm, and an even bigger mystery is how to write SQL for it, as I'm a newbie.

I was thinking about maybe selecting all unique user_id's in general over the year and adding them to a temporary table. Then counting every user's amount of impressions month after month and checking: 1) if in one month imp were < 3;    2) and if in some other month imp > 3.  And if these conditions were not met, then that user_id had to be removed from a temporary table.

After that, the number of suitable users could be summed and received.

It does feel like a huge over complication of things. So maybe someone knows a better/simpler/nicer way to get these results.

Comment: please only tag the databse you are actualy using also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Answer (score 0):

I have put what I think is the start of a solution in the fiddle:
[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8af0d1/22/0)

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE usr 
    (user_id int, Name varchar(5), Age int)
;
    
INSERT INTO usr 
    (user_id, Name, Age)
VALUES
    (1, 'John', 12),
    (2, 'Annie', 29),
    (3, 'John', 44)
;

CREATE TABLE impre
    (user_id int, imp int, datez datetime)
;
    
INSERT INTO impre
    (user_id, imp, datez)
VALUES
    (1, 5, '2012-03-12 00:00:00'),
    (1, 3, '2012-03-15 00:00:00'),
    (1, 3, '2012-04-17 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2012-04-13 00:00:00'),
    (2, 2, '2012-04-15 00:00:00'),
    (2, 1, '2012-05-07 00:00:00'),
    (3, 1, '2012-05-08 00:00:00'),
    (3, 5, '2012-06-07 00:00:00')
;
```

Query:

```
select * from (
    select user_id, SUM(imp) IMPRESSIONS, MONTH(datez)
    from impre
    group by MONTH(datez), user_id
    order by user_id
  ) as tb
where IMPRESSIONS >= 3
```

What it does is that it is aggregating each user based on the amount of impressions and also by the month. The inner `select` is the table where the aggregation is happening, and the outer `select` is the filtering.

I am just not sure what it really means to have less than 3 impressions in ONE month and in ANY other month have more than 3 impressions. Does it mean that we are looking for user_ids that have at least one month with total impressions less than 3, and also any other month greater than 3?

Could you explain the logic programmatically?